# How to override method for "formatting by %" of str's subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a class that inherits the `str` class but uses the `%` operator, not for formatting, but for making the code just like below.

```
print(StrSubclass("11") % 2)
# "11 % 2"
```

I'd like to override the method for that, but I can't find it by calling the `__getattribute__` method that prints what attribute was called (nothing was printed).

Please teach me how to implement this (or if it is not possible).

Thank you.

Comment: What's the logic behind the example you gave?

Comment: I thought that I could implement by these code `def __divmod__(self, other): return "{} % {}".format(self, repr(other))`

Comment: `__divmod__` will overload the `divmod()` built-in function. You should use `__mod__`.

Comment: thank you for commening rdas. and for answer Selcuk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overload the `%` operator using the [`__mod__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mod__) method:

```
class StrSubClass(str):
    def __mod__(self, other):
        return "{} % {}".format(self, other)

print(StrSubClass("11") % 2)
```

output:

```
11 % 2
```